# Unit testing multiple sequential 'put' calls in redux saga

Tags: redux-saga

I have an already written saga which had 4-5 yield in it and appropriate unit tests written for it. But now as part of a defect correction, I had to add another yield put(actionA)(A) effect just before the last yield put(actionB)(B) effect in the saga. So, as expected one of my test cases is failing which tested (B) previously.

So, since I am just adding another yield to the saga, to make my previous tests run correctly, I just added another generator.next() call to the unit test, to make it go to the last yield. But for some reason that doesn't rectify it.

Is there something which I need to do different when adding one more yield put(action) effect?

Sorry if I am not able to show a lot of code and can only explain conceptually, because I don't have the code in front of me right now but need an answer for this. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old but I ran across it when trying to fix this same issue so posting the answer here.

I put this at the beginning of my test for this saga function

`beforeEach(() => { generator = sagaFunctionYouAreTesting(MOCK_ACTION_PAYLOAD);`});

If yield put(actionB)(B) relies on some sort of response from yield put(actionA)(A) you need to pass that to your next function like below

```
 // first we see that action A is called
  expect(generator.next().value.call).toEqual(
    call(
      api.actionA,
      'any params here'
    ).call
  );

 // lets pretend action A returns an array for action B to use
  const mockActionAResult = [{ id: '12345', name: 'foo' }];

  // then we check that action B is called
  expect(
    generator.next(mockActionAResult).value.call
  ).toEqual(call(api.actionB, 'any params here').call);

// lets pretend action B returns success or failure
const mockActionBResult = {status: 200}

// then you could keep going down the line or check for something like a success 
  expect(
    generator.next(mockActionBResult).value
  ).toEqual(
    put({
      type: 'SUCCESS'
    })
  );
```